# Convert string into list of words

Tags: sml, smlnj

How can I pass a string and convert it to a list of words in sml?

For example: `"one two three"` to `["one", "two", "three"]`

Comment: You can split the string using a space, " ". This example is very similar but will need a little bit of tweeking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289155/sml-splitting-string-on-first-space

Answer (score 1):

You can (and probably should) use `String.tokens`:

```
- String.tokens Char.isSpace "one two three";
> val it = ["one", "two", "three"] : string list
```

There is also `String.fields`. They differ in how they treat consecutive/superfluous separators:

```
- String.tokens Char.isSpace "  one  two  three  ";
> val it = ["one", "two", "three"] : string list
- String.fields Char.isSpace "  one  two  three  ";
> val it = ["", "", "one", "", "two", "", "three", "", ""] : string list
```

If your string has multiple potential separators and you're just interested in the words:

```
fun isWordSep c = Char.isSpace c orelse
                ( Char.isPunct c andalso c <> #"-" andalso c <> #"'" )
val words = String.tokens isWordSep
```

This works for one definition of what a word is:

```
- words "I'm jolly-good.  Are you?";
> val it = ["I'm", "jolly-good", "Are", "you"] : string list
```

Not all natural language will abide by this definition, e.g. *e.g.* being an acronym rather than two words, *e* and *g*. For any accuracy you're headed into Natural Language Processing land.